# How do I target the styles of an Angular component from within the CSS file of that component?

Tags: angular

I want to be able to target the actual component so that I can style it. By this I don't mean that I want to target the elements inside the component, but rather the component itself.

For example, if I run `ng g c nav`, this creates a new component called `nav`, which I use in template using `<app-nav></app-nav>`.

I want to be able to style the actual `<app-nav></app-nav>` element from within the nav.component.css file that is created by the above command.

What I've been doing up until now is putting a `<div class="container"></div>` element inside each component that I create, then that holds the styling for the component. But I'm aware this isn't right and I want to do it properly.

I can style the component by going to the parent component and selecting it via the parent's css file, or through the styles.css global file. However I'd prefer to be able to do it from the nav's css file instead. I thought that the `:host` selector would allow me to do this, but it doesn't.

Update: This is what my project looks like.

App.component.html

```
<nav></nav>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Nav.component.css

```
:host{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: The `:host` selector is the right way to go. Why do you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @LeonRadley Because I have `:host{width: 100%; height: 50px; background-color: red;` in my nav.component.css file and it doesn't produce any change

Comment: I've updated the op with my project structure

Comment: Don't confuse `<nav>` with `<app-nav>` with only the latter being the selector of your component, the first is a native html element

Comment: @devnull69 Okay I've changed nav to app-nav, however now my element has a size of 0x0 and the :host still isn't working

Comment: Can you try `display: block` instead of `width: 100%`? Block level elements should naturally take the full parent width

Comment: @devnull69 It works now, thank you. Why was the width: 100% causing a problem?

Comment: @Jake12342134 all component has initial as display default so you neet to update this and set the default as you desire block or inline-block

Comment:  https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5960

Answer (score 3):

This is what the `:host` pseudo selector has been created for

Inside of your `nav` component CSS:

```css
:host {
   border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I read your last line now ... but this is how it is supposed to work. So the problem must then be somewhere else

Comment: Keep in mind that it only works on ViewEncapsulation.Emulated. For ViewEncapsulation.None, you can use the component selector.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways you can use change the component style one from the component style file

```
:host {
  width : 100%;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}
```

another way from the global style file but here you need to use the component tag selector

```
nav {
  color: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px dashed;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
```

[**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2kv15z)

Answer (score 0):

all custom elements such as app-nav have `display: inline` as standard which causes all kinds of problems.

So you should always add `display: block` to all your components to make them behave more like divs.

I think this is your main problem.